# Simulate an already installed operating system

Tags: 11.10, virtualization

First I have to add that I do not know how to explain what I want in the title so if anybody has a better idea be my guess. Here it goes:

I have Windows 7 installed in one of my hard drives. The whole drive is for Windows. As I installed Windows 7 on it, it partitioned the drive into 2 parts. One is called the "System Reserved" and the other is where Program Files and the rest of the directories are.

I wish to run this Windows 7 already installed, in some kind of Virtual environment (Like virtualbox, xen or similar) from Ubuntu. Is there a virtual environment that I can tell it to run this windows 7 from within Ubuntu.

I may be going out of the box out here but is this possible with any tool that Ubuntu comes with.

Comment: Is there any tools to convert partition to vdi file

Comment: Why don't you make a ISO of your System and then install it into the VM?

Comment: In theory, you can boot your windows partition from virtualbox (or KVM) , but it is technical and prone to errors. See http://johanv.org/node/164 or google search for similar. IMO it is better to migrate the windows install to a virtual disk. See - https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Migrate_Windows - again it is "untested" with windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest installing `virt-manager` and virtualisation infrastructure, `libvirt-bin`. You should be able to use virt-manager to create a virtual machine for your Windows 7 install.

This will run the OS in a KVM virtual machine. Unfortunately, you may find that the system is a little slower than when run natively. If performance is a concern for you (are you looking to run games?), then you may want to look into a VMWare or virtualbox solution instead. If performance isn't a big issue, then I'd recommend using KVM, as it works well within Ubuntu, and is completely open source.

To do this: use the virt-manager program to create your new Windows VM.

In the configuration screens, you should simply be able to connect the existing disk (eg, `/dev/sdb`) to the new virtual machine, and use that disk as the boot device.

No need to convert your disk to any other type of virtual storage, it should be usable as-is. I've used this method to test out the Windows 8 beta, so I assume it will work with Windows 7.

In case it helps, here's my virtual machine configuration (generated with `virsh dumpxml <name>`):

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>win8</name>
  <uuid>---uuid removed---/uuid>
  <memory>2097152</memory>
  <currentMemory>2097152</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-1.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source dev='/dev/sdc'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:0e:17:a5'/>
      <source network='isolated'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```